# foreach .. variables of type 'TodoTable' because 'TodoTable' does not contain a public instance or extension definition for 'GetEnumerator' Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have my View page below:

```
@model ToDoListApp.Models.TodoTable

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Urgent";
}

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <p>@item.Id</p>
    <p>@item.Name</p>
}
```

Model:

```cs
namespace ToDoListApp.Models
{
    public partial class TodoTable
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
        public bool Done { get; set; }
        public bool Urgent { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

Controller:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Urgent(short id)
{
    var Task = db.TodoTables.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Id == id);
    return View("Urgent", Task);
}
```

But I am getting an error:

[image]

How I can solve the problem?

Comment: can you show yor TodoTable class pls

Comment: Sorry, I forgot. I edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution for `IEnumerable`**

Your ViewModel is not an `IEnumerable` and the `foreach` loop requires iterating an `IEnumerable` value.

Modify the `@model` as `IEnumerable<ToDoListApp.Models.TodoTable>` type:

```
@model IEnumerable<ToDoListApp.Models.TodoTable>
```

And make sure that your controller action returns the ViewModel as `IEnumerable<ToDoListApp.Models.TodoTable>` type.

```cs
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Urgent(short id)
{
    IEnumerable<TodoTable> tasks = db.TodoTables
        .Where(i => i.Id == id)
        .ToList();

    return View("Urgent", tasks);
}
```

---

**Solution for a single object**

Seems your controller action returns **a single object**, then you shouldn't use the `foreach` loop in the View.

```
@model ToDoListApp.Models.TodoTable

<p>@Model.Id</p>
<p>@Model.Name</p>
```

Comment: Hello, now I'm getting this error too: https://imgur.com/a/b2fvjDp

Comment: Can you share your controller action method? From your screenshot, it seems the action doesn't return the ViewModel `IEnumerable` (array), but it returns an object.

Comment: Done update the answer based on your controller action.